# Package to build custom client to consume an API in Python based on a configuration file?

Tags: python, rest, package

I am new to working with APIs in general and am writing code in python that needs to consume/interact with an API someone else has set up. I was wondering if there is any package out there that would build some sort of custom client class to interact with an API given a file outlining the API in some way (like a json or something where each available endpoint and http verb could be outlined in terms of stuff like allowed payload json schema for posts, general params allowed and their types, expected response json schema, the header key/value for a business verb, etc.). It would be helpful if I could have one master file outlining the endpoints available and then some package uses that to generate a client class we can use to consume the API as described.

In my googling most API packages I have found in python are much more focused on the generation of APIs but this isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I believe you are looking for the built in `requests` package.

```
response = requests.get(f'{base_url}{endpoint}',
                        params={'foo': self.bar,
                                'foo_2':self.bar_2},
                        headers={'X-Api-Key': secret}
                        )
```

And from here, you can build you own class, pass it to a dataframe or whatever.
In the requests package is basically everything you need. Status handling, exception handling everything you need.

Please check the docs.

https://pypi.org/project/requests/